# ObjectInputStream.readObject() does not throw an exception when disconnected

Tags: java, serialization, tcp

I'm using a `ObjectStream` over a TCP connection to send data from a client to a server. Sometimtes the client is terminated while the server still waits for new data. In these cases `readObject()` is staying blocked without of throwing a Exception and my computation stops.

How can i determine if the `ObjectStream` is disconnected or only waiting for more data?

Using a timeout is difficult because of long delays between communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only safe way is to use a timeout. I suspect the long delay you are seeing in detecting a disconnect is due to the nature of the network you have.

Is it really a problem if computation of a dead connection has stopped. This may waste resources for a short period but you should detect a failure within minutes and clean resources then.

Comment: Thanks ill try timeouts with some "areyouthere?"-Messages to test whether the connection is down.

Comment: You are send a heartbeat object. If you send the same one each time, it will be an efficient way to send a heartbeat.